# Trying to Make a Dynamic Named Range using Indirect

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Here is my formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"$A$1:$M"&(INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"A:A"),COUNTA(INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"A:A")))))
```

I am trying to "print" a table on the "Loss Template" worksheet when the data is on different sheets. I was trying to use indirect() to name the worksheet the data needs to come from because the data changes row sizes depending on the worksheet selected. I got this formula to work to "print" 1 worksheet but not the another one yet.

The main problem is I get a #REF error when the "Loss Template" $S$33 changes values.

Comment: INDEX does not return a number but a value, in this case the value at the bottom of the list in A:A.  If that value is not a number this will error.  I think you want: `=INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"$A$1:$M"&COUNTA(INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"A:A")))`

Comment: Thank you so much!  I guess I needed another set of eyes to look at it! I was close and there was nothing exactly like this situation all over the internet but was able to construct this with various pieces I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

As per Scott Craner above, this worked.

=INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"$A$1:$M"&COUNTA(INDIRECT("'"&'Loss Template'!$S$33&"'!"&"A:A")))